# Input type casting?

Tags: c++, casting, char, int

I wanted to take an input char and then from that get a predefined number which was assigned to the char. 
Example

```
int A=100;
char in;
cin>>in; //input A;
```

and then use that `in` char to identify with `A` and pass the value it holds.

sorry if i am not that clear.

Comment: So you want to [*map*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) from some character to the value stored in `A`?

Comment: Use `scanf( "%c", &in );` or `getc` and will get what necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment on your question, you'd want to use a `map`

```
#include <map>
...
std::map<char, int> char_map = {
    {'A', 100}   
};

char in;
std::cin >> in; //input A;

std::cout << char_map[in] << std::endl;
```

Of course you would probably need to add some form of verification on the key.

Comment: wanted to know , can i add the values assigned later on if need be ? 
say: 

A+B.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    std::unordered_map<char, int> uMap;

    for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
    {
        uMap[i] = i - 'A' + 1;
    }

    c = fgetc(stdin);

    std::cout << "\nCharacter '" << c << "' has value " << uMap[c];

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
1. A
2. C
3. Z
```

**Output**

```
1. Character 'A' has value 100
2. Character 'C' has value 102
3. Character 'Z' has value 125
```

Answer (score 0):

your input is a char so you can compare it against some other chars too

```
char input;
std::cin >> input; //input A;
std::cout << "input: " << input << std::endl;
if (input == 'A')
{
    std::cout << "input was A: " << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "input was not: " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys , ill try and use the MAP library and see where i can get with it. appreciate it ,

Comment: good one!! please consider to accept the answer to the one that best help out